# Rails link_to_if problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, switch-statement

I have a helper method designed generate a link to a certain path depending on the current page the user is on. Basically, site wide the link should point to items_path, unless the user is on the user page. So, I'm trying to work out some DRY logic, but I keep running into trouble:

```
def items_link(title, options = {}, html_options = {})
  path = request.path

  case path
  when users_path,items_path
    options = request.parameters.merge(options)
  end

  link_to_if(path == users_path, title, users_path(options), html_options) do
    link_to(title, items_path(options), html_options)
  end
end
```

With this solution items_path throws a `No route matches` error, although the route is correct. users_path works fine, until I switch around the link_to_if path with link_to's.

```
link_to_if(path == items_path, title, items_path(options), html_options) do
  link_to(title, users_path(options), html_options)
end
```

So I am guessing my problem is somewhere in link_to_if. Am I close? My current working solution is:

```
def items_link(title, options = {}, html_options = {})
path = request.path

case path
when users_path
  options = request.parameters.merge(options)
  link_to(title, users_path(options), html_options)
when items_path
  options = request.parameters.merge(options)
  link_to(title, items_path(options), html_options)
else
  link_to(title, users_path(options), html_options)
end
end
```

This works fine, it's just ugly.

**Update:**

I spent some more time and figured I had to break it out a little more, and this actually helped me in another area, I like having the link_action helper.

```
  def items_link(title, options = {}, html_options = {})
    link_to(title, items_link_action(options), html_options)
  end

  def items_link_action(options = {})
    path = request.path

    case path
    when users_path,items_path
      options = request.parameters.merge(options)
    end

    if path == users_path
      users_path(options) 
    else
      items_path(options)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as close as I got, works pretty well I think.

```
def items_link(title, options = {}, html_options = {})
  link_to(title, items_link_action(options), html_options)
end

def items_link_action(options = {})
  path = request.path

  case path
  when users_path,items_path
    options = request.parameters.merge(options)
  end

  if path == users_path
    users_path(options) 
  else
    items_path(options)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it make sense to be throwing the same options into either link?  That may be the source of your No Route Matches error.

I would look at the current_page? helper and the link_to_unless_current helpers.

Something like this would show a link to the users index action unless they are already at the users index action.  The same could be done for the items page.  Not sure if this is what you were looking for though.  If it were me I'd just drop two links in my layout or a shared partial:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "Users", users_path %>
<%= link_to_unless_current "Items", items_path %>
```

Comment: I actually need the link to still work on the page, think of sort links. Its a weird problem, and hard to describe, however I think I may have found my solution, see edit.

Comment: @noazark I think you would better to post your edited content as a new answer and accept so that the others know that the problem is solved, unless you think your edited content still need improvements.

Comment: I'll definitely be doing that. I'm refining the solution right now.